# Copying a specific file from one path to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, copy, cydia, tweak

hello everyone im trying to create this tweak that copies a file from one spot to another everytime a specific app opens. Would this be correct to use. im still really new to this, but trying, what command should be placed to have this run everytime the app opens.

```
- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager 
 shouldCopyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath *path/to/where/file/is 
 toPath:(NSString *)dstPath *where/i/want/it/copied/to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to run every time the app opens then you can call it from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in your app delegate.

Comment: Seems kinda dumb I answered this a year later but I was a rookie back then and didn't understand SO. Thank you for your help.